# Executing Abaqus Model in Taverna

Tags: ssh, scp, beanshell, abaqus, taverna

I'm pretty new to both Taverna and Abaqus but I am trying to run an Abaqus model using a "Tool" in Taverna remotely on a HPC. This works fine if I already have my model file and inputs on the HPC but I need a way of uploading the files dynamically in Taverna (trying to generically wrap Abaqus models).

I've tried adding a input port that takes a file list but I don't know how I can copy it to the "location" that I've set for the tool. Could a beanshell service be the answer or can I iterate through the file list and copy them up before executing the abaqus model?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say that you created an input port that takes a file list, I guess you mean an input to the tool service.

Assuming the input port is called my_file_list, when the tool service is run, it will take a list of data values on port my_file_list. As an example, say it has "hello", "hi" and "hola" is the three values in the list.

On the location where the tool service is run, it executes in a temporary directory - a different directory for each execution of the service. It is normally something like /tmp/usecase-2029778474741087696

Three files will be created in the temporary directory; those files contain the (in this example) three values the tool service received on port my_file_list. The files could be called

- /tmp/usecase-2029778474741087696/tempfile.0.tmp containing hello
- /tmp/usecase-2029778474741087696/tempfile.1.tmp containing hi
- /tmp/usecase-2029778474741087696/tempfile.2.tmp containing hola

There will also be a file called my_input_list. That file will contain

```
/tmp/usecase-2029778474741087696/tempfile.0.tmp
/tmp/usecase-2029778474741087696/tempfile.1.tmp
/tmp/usecase-2029778474741087696/tempfile.2.tmp
```

The script of your tool service would normally read the contents of my_input_list line by line and do something with the contents of the listed file(s).

I have also seen some scripts that 'cheat' and iterate directly over tempfile*.tmp but that would be "a bad thing". The problem with that trick, is that if you want to add a second list of files to the tool service then the file my_input_list could contain

```
/tmp/usecase7932018053449784034/tempfile.4.tmp
/tmp/usecase7932018053449784034/tempfile.5.tmp
/tmp/usecase7932018053449784034/tempfile.6.tmp
```

as other temporary files were used for the other file list port.

I hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

The tool service allows you to [upload files](http://dev.mygrid.org.uk/wiki/display/tav250/File+inputs) - but if you are using the HPC through a job submission node, then you would have to modify your command line tool to then use the job file staging command to further push the files as part of the job. The files would be available in the current (temporary) directory of the specified tool script.

I would try to do it through the Tool service and not involve the beanshell - then you can keep your workflow simpler.

A good thing to remember is that you can write multiple shell commands in the box.

Similarly you would probably want to retrieve back the results so that you can process them further in the workflow (unless they are massive - in which case you should just output their remote filenames and send them in again to the next HPC job)

The exact commands to use for staging files and retrieving them depends on the HPC job submission system. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the input guys.
It was my misunderstanding of how Taverna uses the File list. All the files in the list are copied to the temp "sandbox" and are therefore available for use.
Another nice easy way is to zip the directory and pass the zipped files into an input port for the service. Then just unzip the files inside the command.
Thanks again